# MUI Autocomplete - render image in list

Tags: material-ui, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the [MUI Autocomplete component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) for Google places autocomplete, and I need to add an image for "powered by google" to the end of the list, and don't want it to be a selectable item.

I know you can render the individual items with `renderOption`, but is there some way I can add custom render logic to the list itself, like adding a div to the bottom of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out: I just needed to add a custom `ListboxComponent` and pass it to the `Autocomplete`.

Here's the custom component:

```js
function ListboxComponent(props) {
  return(
    <>
      <ul
        {...props}
      />
      <img src={googleLogo}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

And I set up the `Autocomplete` as follows:

```js
<Autocomplete
   ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
   [...]
/>
```

Works like a charm. Note that this only renders the image when there are options-- if options is empty, it doesn't render it.